# Why is my method returning None?

Tags: python

I have the following method call:

```
NCOLS = 3        
NPEGS = 4 

first_guess = []

print("calling first guess method")
first_guess = firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess)
print("after method call: " + str(first_guess))
```

firstGuess method:

```
def firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess):
"""Used for setting up the first guess of the game"""
  print("in firstGuess method")
  for c in range(1, NCOLS + 1):
     if len(first_guess) == NPEGS:
         print("about to return first guess: " + str(first_guess))
         return first_guess
     else:
         first_guess.append(c)

  print("out of for loop, first_guess len is " + str(len(first_guess)) + ", " + str(first_guess))
  if len(first_guess) <= NPEGS: #there were less color options than pegs
     firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess)
```

This seems to be returning `None` for a reason I cannot figure out.

Here is my output:

```
calling first guess method
in firstGuess method
out of for loop, first_guess len is 3, [1, 2, 3]
in firstGuess method
about to return first guess: [1, 2, 3, 1]
after method call: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mastermind.py", line 323, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "mastermind.py", line 318, in main
playOnce()
File "mastermind.py", line 160, in playOnce
first_guess = first_guess + str(g[0][i])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is it returning `None` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're hitting is that your recursive call doesn't return its result.

So, it prints "out of for loop…", then it makes a recursive call. That recursive call then successfully returns something… but the outer call ignores that and falls off the end, which means you get `None`.

Just add a `return` before the call to `firstGuess`:

```
print("out of for loop, first_guess len is " + str(len(first_guess)) + ", " + str(first_guess))
if len(first_guess) <= NPEGS: #there were less color options than pegs
   return firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess)
```

This still leaves a path where you don't return anything (if you get to "out of for loop", and then `len(first_guess) > NPEGS`)… but you don't have any logic to do anything useful there. You may want to add some kind of `assert` or `raise` if you believe that could never happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are paths through your code that do not end with you explicitly returning anything.

Where you're calling `firstGuess` recursively, you should be doing `return firstGuess(...)`? Though, there will still be a case where you fall through and don't return anything. You should add a final `return first_guess` statement after the final `if` statement.

Try this:

```
def firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess):
  """Used for setting up the first guess of the game"""
  print("in firstGuess method")
  for c in range(1, NCOLS + 1):
     if len(first_guess) == NPEGS:
         print("about to return first guess: " + str(first_guess))
         return first_guess
     else:
         first_guess.append(c)

  print("out of for loop, first_guess len is " + str(len(first_guess)) + ", " + str(first_guess))
  if len(first_guess) <= NPEGS: #there were less color options than pegs
     return firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess)
  return first_guess
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last two lines to

```
if len(first_guess) <= NPEGS: #there were less color options than pegs
    return firstGuess(NCOLS, NPEGS, first_guess)
else:
    # what do you do here?  return something
    return first_guess
```

You're not returning in all branches